# How should I handle function calls between controllers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to build an Angular app that consists of a fullscreen map and a sidebar.

I currently have a MapController that setups the map and then I have a PlacesController for listing places in the sidebar. If I now would like to add a marker to the map by clicking a link in the sidebar, how should this be handled?

My idea:
The PlacesController have a function called addMarker that calls another function called addMarker in a service that broadcasts "addMarker" using "$rootScope.$broadcast('addMarker');" which the MapController listens for and then calls "addMarker" in the MapController which actually adds the marker to the map.

Is there an easier/better way of doing this?

Comment: Move the code for working with maps to a service and use that service in both controllers. Your idea sounds really bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the data all contained in some service that notifies any listeners when it is changed.  **Edit** Here is a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/karobakodapi/1/edit) demonstrating this method

The observer pattern would be good for this one:

```
app.factory('MapService', function() {
  var observerCallbacks = [];
  var markers = [];

  var publicMembers = {
    addMarker: addMarker,
    getMarkers: getMarkers,
    registerObserverCallback: registerObserverCallback
  }

  function addMarker (marker) {
     markers.push(marker);
     notifyObservers();
  };

  function getMarkers() {
     return markers;
  }

  function registerObserverCallback(callback){
    observerCallbacks.push(callback);
  };

  function notifyObservers(){
    angular.forEach(observerCallbacks, function(callback){
      callback();
    });
  };

  return publicMembers;
});
```

And then in your controller you can can inject this service, register as an observer, and any time observers are notified (e.g., in `addMarker`, your callback will be executed:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, MapService) {
    MapService.registerObserverCallback(function() {
        $scope.markers = MapService.getMarkers();
    });
});
```